# Angular-tags typeahead allowing duplicate values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typeahead.js

Here is a plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/PaG1k5N37BTOflObnN7K?p=preview

`Typeahead` is working perfectly. However, the problem is that, it is letting me add duplicate values. For example, if `Marie` is already added to the `tag` element, it lets me add it again. Is there a way to make `typeahead` only display suggestions that have not already been added.

I think `decipher.tags.addfailed` event should be used to solve this. I couldn't get it to work though.

**UPDATE**

With the help of `Daniel_L's` answer, I figured out a solution for my problem.

When `decipher.tags.added` event is triggered, `tagAdded()` is called. I wrapped this callback function  inside a `$timeout`. Doing this updated the `$scope.to` property as `$timeout` calls `$apply()` internally.

Here is a working pluker - http://plnkr.co/edit/elPefHusJMunHEOhP0HI?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

According to their [source code](https://github.com/boneskull/angular-tags/blob/master/dist/angular-tags-0.3.1.js#L91) `decipher.tags.added` is the name an `emit` event, so you in order to access the tag the user added you have to do:

```
$scope.$on("decipher.tags.added", function(info, obj) {
    console.log(obj.tag); //get the tag info
});
```

To prevent a tag from being added multiple times you'd need to splice the array after every event. Not sure how to get past angular's buggy `$scope.apply()` behavior, however.

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular
    .module("plunker", ["decipher.tags", "ui.bootstrap"])
    .controller("EmailViewController", ["$scope", EmailViewController]);

  function EmailViewController($scope) {
    $scope.to = [
      { name: "John", value: "John" },
      { name: "Marie", value: "Marie" },
      { name: "Ghita", value: "Ghita" },
      { name: "Marghioala", value: "Marg" }
    ];
    $scope.info = { select: [] };
    $scope.typeaheadOpts = {
      minLength: 1
    };
    $scope.$on("decipher.tags.added", tagAdded);

    function tagAdded(info, obj) {
      var index = find($scope.to, {name: obj.tag.name});
      if (index >= 0) $scope.to.splice(index, 1); //removes from array bound to scope
    }

    function find(obj, pred) {
      var key = Object.keys(pred)[0];
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj[i][key] === pred[key]) return i;
      }
    }
  }

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. When the event `decipher.tags.added` is triggered, why are `info` and `obj` needed to access the entered `tag` name? When I use `obj` without `info`, I get an error.

Comment: Those are the arguments sent to the callback by the `$on` method. There's no way around it, you must include both arguments.